# Why should I convert & to &amp; in XSS prevention?

Tags: security, xss, websecurity

Recently I've been thinking about a question as I mention in the title.

As [OWASP](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_(Cross_Site_Scripting)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet) suggest us in their RULE #1, one should do some HTML escape before inserting user input into HTML pages.

However, in cases below:

<tag>userInput</tag>

<tag attribute="userInput"></tag>

If I only escape 4 character: < > ' ", but not &, is there any payload could cause XSS? Notice that &quot; in userInput could not make attribute closed.

Or is there any cases that character & have to be escaped, otherwise there will be XSS vulnerabilities exist?

Answer (score 1):

Here is something you should consider:

> `&lt;` is `<` and `&gt;` is `>`

You can see the `&` is being used for indicating an escape point.

So if you want to enter the `&` instead of `&amp;` browsers (parser) might consider it as a escape point.

That's why you need to use `&amp;` instead of `&`.

Comment: Thank u for ur reply, however I still can't not figure it out that Is there any vulnerability of allowing user enter character &. It is a escape point, but I consider that it can not let injecting new tag or attribute become possible. Or am I making any mistake?

Comment: `&` is not opening any xss vulnerability. but you should escape it to escape a escaper.

Comment: But you should consider this `&` in your backend code. suppose you are running a command on your system by user input. so `whoami && sudo rm -rf /*` is a risk here. escaping and sanitization is the only way to prevent it.